# Creating event id from database?

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm populating the calendar with a json feed.

```
$return_arr = array();
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 $row_array['rowid'] = $row['id'];
     $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
     $row_array['start'] = $row['start'];
     $row_array['end'] = $row['end'];

array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
      }

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

And render the event:

```
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
title: 'title',
start: start,
end: end,
allDay: allDay,
id: rowid
},
true // make the event "stick"          
);
```

When I use eventClick to get the id I get _fc1, _fc2 etc. Is there anyway I can get the id generated by my database? so I can refer to each individual event for updating?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple add a custom field to your *Event* and then reference that in your click event.

From the [Docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

> Non-standard Fields
>
> In addition to the fields above, you may also include your own
>   non-standard fields in each Event Object. FullCalendar will not modify
>   or delete these fields. For example, developers often include a
>   description field for use in callbacks such as eventRender.

Comment: Ive tired adding a custom ID, however, using calEvent.id I keep getting undefined.

Comment: Are you sure that your customID is part of the json being returned? Are any other custom fields coming through?

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the issue, you can accept an answer by clicking on the hollow check-mark to the left of the answer. Alternatively if none of the existing answers solved your problem and you you came up with a different solution then you should post your own solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same DBid as [event](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) id: `$row_array['id'] = $row['id'];`.

In `eventClick(event,...)` you will get it as `event.id`.

Comment: @Matthisco hi,I am facing a similar problem...how did you solve the issue.

Comment: @Dimitris Papageorgiou
To use unique event.id, as required by event object, I suggested using the same DB id, assuming it is a unique key...

Comment: @MaxD I am using the id provided by the DB...after searching a little...the problem in my case is that while the server sends the ID in the response...fullCalendar seems not to get it and as such,creates its own ids(_fc1,_fc2...etc)unless i refresh the page...the problem with FullCalendar v2.2.